# Fetch call in React creating some unexpected results when rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

**Problem summary**

I'm attempting to display a set of three newsfeeds. Each newsfeed draws from a specific RSS feed.

My React Newsfeeds component receives a list of newsfeeds as props. Each item in that list has the RSS URL that I need to fetch from for each specific feed. However, for the purposes of this question, I'm not really using that data. In this case, for testing, I'm just using the same URL for all three newsfeeds.

I'm successfully retrieving each specific newsfeed RSS using a fetch call in `componentDidMount()`. Each feed is getting built by the `mapFeed()` function which is making the `fetch` call and constructing the HTML. These feeds are getting stored in the `feeds` state variable.

Finally, my component is supposed to be rendering this `feeds` state variable.

Something is getting lost in translation or there's something obvious that I'm missing, but by the time we get to the last `render()` I'm not able to access the information inside each feed.

**What I've tried**

Here is what I've tried, and my leads:

1. I've tried logging any state changes into my console. I see that my `this.state.stories` array doesn't get fetched right away. I believe this is due to `fetch` working asynchronously. Once it gets fetched completely, I see that `this.state.stories` gets updated but no further rendering occurs.
2. All my function logs (i.e `entering function A...`) are getting logged before the fetch call finishes getting the data. I'm unsure if this is due to the nature of the console and/or whether things are getting logged in time. But this feels like a clue
3. I've tried updating `this.state.feeds` once more after the `fetch` call finishes. But this doesn't trigger a re-render either.
4. I've dug through all kinds of different fetch `code` examples here to see if there's anything wrong with my `fetch` call, but none of them seem to fix the issue.

I'm sorry if this is kind of messy. I'm still at a basic-intermediate level with React, and I'm trying to grasp the concept of fetch.

Thanks for your support

**My Code**

```
class Newsfeeds extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rssUrl: '', // current RSS URL
      stories: null, // stories for the current feed getting mapped
      feeds: null, // newsfeeds
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFeeds()
  }

  getFeeds() {
    const feeds = this.props.data.list.map((item, index) => this.mapFeed(item, index));

    this.setState({
      feeds: feeds
    })
  }


  mapFeed(item, index) {
    const RSS_URL = 'https://www.democracynow.org/democracynow.rss'
    this.setState({ rssUrl: RSS_URL });
    this.getData(RSS_URL);


    return (
      <div className="newsfeed" key={index}>
        <div className="row align-items-center">
          <div className="col-md-9 newsFeedsItemStories">
            {this.getStories()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  getData = async (rssUrl) => {
    await fetch(rssUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          console.log(`Did not get an ok from partner news source. got: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
        return response.text()
      })
      .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
      .then(data => this.setStories(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error getting rss data: ${error.message}`)
      })
  }

  setStories(data) {
    this.setState({
      stories: data.querySelectorAll("item"),
    })
  }

  getStories() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.getTitle(this.state.stories[0])}</h4>
        <p>{this.getDate(this.state.stories[0])}</p>
        <h4>{this.getTitle(this.state.stories[1])}</h4>
        <p>{this.getDate(this.state.stories[1])}</p>
        <h4>{this.getTitle(this.state.stories[2])}</h4>
        <p>{this.getDate(this.state.stories[2])}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  /** Parse news item helper functions */
  getDateStr(story) {
    /** ...... some code to get date */
  }

  getTitle(story) {
    /** ...... some code to get title */
  }

  getUrl(story) {
    /** ...... some code to get url */
  }
  /** End of parse News item helper functions */

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="newsfeeds" id="newsfeeds">
        <h3>Title for my set of newsfeeds</h3>
        <div className="newsfeeds-list">
          {this.state.feeds}
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Newsfeeds;
```

**My console log**

```
mapping feed
this.state.stories: 
null
building html for stories..
this.state.stories: 
null
mapping feed
this.state.stories: 
null
building html for stories..
this.state.stories: 
null
mapping feed
this.state.stories: 
null
building html for stories..
this.state.stories: 
null
component will unmount
mapping feed
this.state.stories: 
null
building html for stories..
this.state.stories: 
null
mapping feed
this.state.stories: 
null
building html for stories..
this.state.stories: 
null
mapping feed
this.state.stories: 
null
building html for stories..
this.state.stories: 
null
componentDidUpdate
State 'rssUrl' changed
State 'feeds' changed
componentDidUpdate
State 'feeds' changed
updating stories state
componentDidUpdate
State 'stories' changed
updating stories state
componentDidUpdate
State 'stories' changed
updating stories state
componentDidUpdate
State 'stories' changed
updating stories state
componentDidUpdate
State 'stories' changed
updating stories state
componentDidUpdate
State 'stories' changed
updating stories state
componentDidUpdate
State 'stories' changed
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to note is that you are using `async/await` with `.then` which isn't necessary.

Also in this line

```js
const feeds = this.props.data.list.map((item, index) => this.mapFeed(item, index));
```

`this.props.data` is undefined if it's not being set. Where is this being passed in?

Either way I'm pretty sure your mistake is here

```js
    this.getData(RSS_URL);
```

this code is most likely not finishing before you call `getStories()` a couple lines down. So your call to `getStories` is mapping nothing

Edit:

The main issue is you trying to update things before theyre ready. Trying to use async data before its loaded and state before it's done being set. Try consolidating

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rssUrl: '', // current RSS URL
      stories: null, // stories for the current feed getting mapped
      feeds: [], // newsfeeds
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFeeds()
  }

  getFeeds() {
    ['item'].map((item, index) => {
      const RSS_URL = 'https://www.democracynow.org/democracynow.rss'
      fetch(RSS_URL)
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(`Did not get an ok from partner news source. got: ${response.statusText}`);
          }
          return response.text()
        })
        .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {
          const stories = data.querySelectorAll("item");

          this.setState((state) => {
            return {feeds: [
              ...state.feeds, 
              stories
            ]}
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(`Error getting rss data: ${error.message}`)
        })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="newsfeeds" id="newsfeeds">
        <h3>Title for my set of newsfeeds</h3>
        <div className="newsfeeds-list">
          {this?.state?.feeds?.map((feed, index) => {
            const stories = [...feed]?.map((item, index) => {
              const title = item.querySelector('title').innerHTML
              return (<div className="newsfeed" key={index}>
                <div className="row align-items-center">
                  <div className="col-md-9 newsFeedsItemStories">
                    <h4>{title}</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>)
            })

            return stories
          })}
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The data that’s getting passed to the component is definitely valid. I was logging it and testing if before I delved into all of this. 

If the problem is as you think, what would be the way to call getData and let it finish before getStories gets called? I don’t know how I would address that

Comment: @user2030942 honestly i would consolidate all the code. This problems you're having is because you're updating state and while that state is in the qeue you're trying to perform operations with it
 
I'll add another answer

Answer (score 0):

Following @user2030942 's advice, I've simplified my code heavily and it now works perfectly. Here is my solution if anybody else has this problem. I added a new variable isFetching, to not render anything unless fetching is done. I also added a couple `?` in my map functions to check if data is ready before proceeding.

```
class Newsfeeds extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      active: -1,
      rssUrl: '',
      feeds: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFeeds()
  }

  /** setActive() sets the active feed for the toggle */

  setActive(index) {
    if (this.state.active != index) {
      this.setState(
        { active: index }
      )
    } else {
      this.setState(
        { active: -1 }
      )
    }
  }

  /** Parse news item helper functions */

  getDateStr(story) {
    const month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    const date = new Date(story.querySelector("pubDate").innerHTML);

    var strDate = 'm d, Y'
      .replace('Y', date.getFullYear())
      .replace('m', month[date.getMonth()])
      .replace('d', date.getDate());

    return strDate;
  }

  getTitle(story) {
    let title = story.querySelector("title").innerHTML;

    return title;
  }

  getUrl(story) {
    return story.querySelector("link").innerHTML;
  }

  /** getFeeds() retrieves the newsfeeds from the RSS url's provided */

  getFeeds() {
    let feeds = []
    let fetchCount = 0
    let numFeeds = this.props.data.list.length

    this.props.data.list.map((item, index) => {
      const RSS_URL = item.rss_feed_url

      fetch(RSS_URL)
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(`Did not get an ok from partner news source. got: ${response.statusText}`)
          }
          return response.text()
        })
        .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {
          const stories = data.querySelectorAll("item:nth-of-type(-n+3)");

          feeds.push(stories)

          this.setState({
            feeds: feeds
          })

          fetchCount++

          if (fetchCount == numFeeds) {
            this.setState({
              isFetching: false
            })
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(`Error getting rss data: ${error.message}`)
        })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isFetching) {
      return false
    } else {
      return (
        <section className={styles.newsfeeds} id="newsfeeds">
          <div className="container">
            <h3>{this.props.data.title}</h3>
            <div className={styles.inner}>
              <div className={styles.newsfeedsList}>
                {
                  this?.state?.feeds?.map((feed, index) => {
                    let numStories = this.state.feeds.length

                    const stories = [...feed]?.map((item, index) => {
                      const title = this.getTitle(item)
                      const date = this.getDateStr(item)
                      const url = this.getUrl(item)

                      if ((index == 0)) {
                        return (
                          <div className={styles.newsFeedsItemStory}>
                            <a href={url}><h4>{title}</h4></a>
                            <p>{date}</p>
                          </div>
                        )
                      } else if (numStories >= 3) {
                        return (
                          <div className={styles['toggle']}>
                            <div className={styles.newsFeedsItemStory}>
                              <a href={url}><h4>{title}</h4></a>
                              <p>{date}</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        )
                      } else {
                        return (
                          <div className="notice">
                            <h4>No stories available for this newsfeed</h4>
                          </div>
                        )
                      }
                    }) // end of stories map

                    return (
                      <div className={`${styles.newsfeedsItem} ${this.state.active === index ? styles['is-active'] : styles['is-hidden']}`} key={index}>
                        <div className="row align-items-center">
                          <div className="col-md-2 newsFeedsItemImg">
                            {
                              this.props.data.list[index] && (
                                <img src={this.props.data.list[index].image.sourceUrl} alt="" />
                              )
                            }
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-md-9 newsFeedsItemStories">
                            {stories}
                          </div>
                          <div className="col-md-1 text-right newsFeedsItemToggle">
                            <div className={styles['expand-feed']} onClick={() => this.setActive(index)}>
                              <button>
                                <span></span>
                                <span></span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )
                  }) // end of data list map
                }
              </div>
            </div >
          </div >
        </section >
      ) // end of render return
    }

  } // end of render
}

export default Newsfeeds;
```